# Do any animals mix porphyrins and carotenoids in their pigmentation?

Tags: biochemistry, pigmentation, melanin

Many animals (particularly birds) use carotenoids or porphyrins in their diet to contribute to the brilliance of their skin/fur/feather coloration. A few even mix melanin in with carotenoids to get more complex colors. But are there any animals that mix a porphyrin with a carotenoid to make their color?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [Here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-49433-1) is one example of an annelid worm that does this:

> Altogether, the endogenous porphyrinoid pigments of E. viridis appear to be similar in function and origin to the coloured bile pigments of H. diversicolor. It must be noted that biliverdin in this latter species is described as a secondary pigment, since the green coloration is only noticeable when the presence of the worm’s main pigments, namely carotenoids, decline during the reproductive phase and/or in starving individuals7. However, in E. viridis, green pigments are unequivocally predominant, likely being homologous to biliverdin, whereas yellow pigments may be more similar to another product of haem breakdown known as bilirubin (also yellow), rather than carotenoids. In fact, the yellow pigments found in the proboscis and epidermis (see Fig. 2) have quite distinct spectra from carotenoids36.

It seems that the original reference that they refer to is [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=On%20the%20diverse%20colours%20of%20Nereis%20diversicolor&journal=J.%20Mar.%20Biol.%20Assoc.%20United%20Kingdom&volume=33&pages=699-708&publication_year=1954&author=Dales%2CRP&author=Kennedy%2CGY), performing a relatively straightforward organic extraction and spectrographic analysis of pigments, stating:

> Worms thus owe their green appearance to biliverdin, while the yellow, brown and orange pigments also present in the epidermis in most worms are carotenoids.

[Biliverdin is a porphyrin](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/biliverdin).